# Adding email from gmail iPhone app as calendar entry in google calendar on iPhone

Tags: iphone, calendar, gmail, google-calendar

For a given google account, I'd like to be able to do the following on my iPhone:

1. Open email in gmail iPhone app.
2. Add the email as a calendar event or appointment on google calendar.

I know I can do this from the web browser. But I have been unable to figure out a way to do this in gmail app on iPhone.

Does anyone know how can I do this ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I cannot find this command in the iOS GMail app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this (yet).